# HTML Display text onto of image in specific place

Tags: mysql, html, image, text

Basically what I have is an image of a map, and I want to place values from a mysql database on top of the map. Each value will go on its own state, so the positioning needs to be precise. For the small states, I am just putting it separately, but my main question is, how can I get the text on top of the image in the right positions?
Also, the mysql value is dynamic, so I can't just put the text in the image. I am trying to use a wysiwyg editor to drag the text onto the image, but it doesn't seem to let me, and if i were to do that, that would be regular text, not mysql values. How would I change that text into mysql values even if i were to do that?
Hopefully someone can answer both my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning with css.

try applying this type of style to the html elements that contain the text.

```
absPositionStyle{
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:150px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I cant position it manually, I need a wsyiwyg editor, but none of the ones that I have found will let me drag a "block" of text.